# Python function calling

Tags: python

I have the following classes:

```
from forwind.lidarapi.api import MCLidarGUIPlugin


class MCLidarActions( Handler ):

    tcp_send = Event

    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        print info;
        pass;   

    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click" )
```

and

```
from forwind.lidarapi.actions.api import MCLidarActions

class MCUDPActions( MCLidarActions ):

    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        pass;   

    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click UDP" )
```

When I click on a button in the `MCLidarActions` the _tcp_send_changed function will be called, how can I extend this function, I want to take action in the MCUDPActions as well. In this case If I click on the button it will printed out `click` but I want to print out `Click UDP` as well

Comment: « When I click on a button in the MCLidarActions....»  : you mean, "in **a** MCLidarActions **instance**", I presume ?  Do you want clicking on ONE button to print "Click" AND "Click UDP", that is to say the two functions _tcp_send_changed of two instances to be activated ? Or to change the consequence of clicking on your button to print "Click UDP" INSTEAD OF "Click" ? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Print out both messages.

Comment: Thank you. I'm happy my answer being useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you problem, you could do:

```
class MCLidarActions( object ):
    li = []

    tcp_send = 'Event'

    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        print info;
        pass;

    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click" )
        for x in self.li:
            x._tcp_send_changed()


class MCUDPActions( MCLidarActions ):
    def __init__(self):
        self.li.append(self)
    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        pass;
    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click UDP" )


class MC_uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_Actions( MCLidarActions ):
    def __init__(self):
        self.li.append(self)
    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        pass;
    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click _uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_" )



M = MCLidarActions()
print 'M, instance of MCLidarActions, created ------------'
print '  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():'
M._tcp_send_changed()


a = MCUDPActions()
print '\na, instance of MCUDPActions, created ------------'
print '  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():'
M._tcp_send_changed()
print
print '  executing  a._tcp_send_changed():'
a._tcp_send_changed()


b = MCUDPActions()
print '\nb, instance of MCUDPActions, created ------------'
print '  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():'
M._tcp_send_changed()
print
print '  executing  a._tcp_send_changed():'
a._tcp_send_changed()
print
print '  executing  b._tcp_send_changed():'
b._tcp_send_changed()


v = MC_uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_Actions()
print '\nv, instance of MC_uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_Actions, created ------------'
print '  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():'
M._tcp_send_changed()
print
print '  executing  a._tcp_send_changed():'
a._tcp_send_changed()
print
print '  executing  b._tcp_send_changed():'
b._tcp_send_changed()
print
print '  executing  v._tcp_send_changed():'
v._tcp_send_changed()
```

result

```
M, instance of MCLidarActions, created ------------
  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():
Click

a, instance of MCUDPActions, created ------------
  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():
Click
Click UDP

  executing  a._tcp_send_changed():
Click UDP

b, instance of MCUDPActions, created ------------
  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():
Click
Click UDP
Click UDP

  executing  a._tcp_send_changed():
Click UDP

  executing  b._tcp_send_changed():
Click UDP

v, instance of MC_uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_Actions, created ------------
  executing  M._tcp_send_changed():
Click
Click UDP
Click UDP
Click _uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_

  executing  a._tcp_send_changed():
Click UDP

  executing  b._tcp_send_changed():
Click UDP

  executing  v._tcp_send_changed():
Click _uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_
```

But in the above code, it is necessary to define a function **__init__** in each subclass **MCUDPActions** and **MC_uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_Actions** of the base class  **MCLidarActions**

To avoid that , the appending in **li** can be put in the base class:

```
class MCLidarActions( object ):
    li = []

    tcp_send = 'Event'

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__ != MCLidarActions:
            self.li.append(self)

    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        print info;
        pass;

    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click" )
        for x in self.li:
            x._tcp_send_changed()




class MCUDPActions( MCLidarActions ):
    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        pass;
    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click UDP" )


class MC_uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_Actions( MCLidarActions ):
    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        pass;
    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( "Click _uuuuuuuuuuuuuutp_" )
```

and the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of calling super()
Beware that you need to inherit object inorder to make super works.

```
class E(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "enter E"
        print "leave E"

class F(E):
    def __init__(self):
        print "enter F"
        super(F, self).__init__()
        print "leave F"

f = F()
```